# Deleting your question only to re-ask it

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions, reposts

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138472/c-custom-error-message-for-my-firewall), the OP admitted to deleting his question and then reposting it. I feel like this user has successfully "gamed" the system. His post is not technically a dupe (since he deleted the original), and it's not offensive (in content) or spam, so it's not flag-worthy.

I left a comment attempting to educate the user. But what else can be done here? I would hate to see this catch on as a way of getting more attention for your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe flag the new question for moderator attention?  A moderator can undelete the original and close the latter as a dupe of the original?

Comment: I think mod-flagging is the best course of action. There is very little to "gain" by doing this instead of traditional bumping. Votes are likely to repeat themselves if the question doesn't really change (if not turn negative from angry hornet rage on the repost). Comments might be lost, which is why flagging it for a moderator to see if content might be lost would be useful. If nothing is lost, there's not even a real need to undelete the old version. Plus, alerting the moderators puts that user on the map, so that any future incidents can be linked.

Answer (score 2):

I downvoted the question; I think that seems appropriate.